# How to securely connect to Google Sheets via API from the front end?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been working with the sheets API for some time. I am aware of libraries such as the this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet

This is written in Javascript, but obviously meant to be used server side. However, my question is this: Is there a secure way to connect to a sheet I own via the front-end? I am aware of services like Sheetsu, but don't really understand how they can guarantee the security of the service account credentials.

Comment: About `connect to a sheet I own via the front-end`, can I ask you about the detail information of your goal? Because, for example, if what you want to do for Spreadsheet has already been decided, I thought that your worries might be reduced by limiting the functions for Spreadsheet. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Maybe [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) could be useful for you?